# Recommended way of implementing a scroll-aware FloatingActionButton

Tags: android, material-design, android-support-library, android-design-library, floating-action-button

I'm Building an app following Material Design and am wondering how to hide the FAB on scroll. Googling leads to several answers, some say provide custom onScrollListeners etc and some say implement a layout behaviour. Is there a standard/recommended way of doing this? and what advantages does one method have over the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way is to use the `FloatingActionButton` provided in the support design library, and redefine its behavior. For example, take a look at [this class](https://github.com/ianhanniballake/cheesesquare/blob/92bcf7c8b57459051424cd512a032c12d24a41b3/app/src/main/java/com/support/android/designlibdemo/ScrollAwareFABBehavior.java).

You can just copy-paste it in your project, and then you assign this behavior to your `FloatingActionButton`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
     android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
     app:layout_behavior="com.your.package.name.ScrollAwareFABBehavior" />
```

Once done, your FAB will react to scroll gestures and automatically hide/show. Of course this, as with all `Behavior`s, only works if you use a `CoordinatorLayout` as the root view.

Benefits:

- uses official libraries;
- uses `Behavior`s which is definitely the easiest way to go for listening to scroll events. Since `FloatingActionButton` is part of the design library (which implements `Behavior`s), I'd say this is pretty much the *official* way;
- that Behavior class was written by Ian Lake, who as far as I know works at google.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That is exactly what I've done for now but  the thing is I also have a toolbar which ive set to scroll away using the scroll flags and the thing is the fab only disappears after the toolbar goes away and the user continues scrolling. I wanted both things to happen at once. Any way ill look into that myself thank you for the answer!

Comment: @user I understand, but I see no workaround for that.

Comment: I've tried to use this with a WebView in the Coordinator layout and it doesn't seem to react to my WebView Scrolling. Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: @clu maybe WebView does not support nested scrolling? Try posting your own question if it doesn't exist yet.